# opening google maps with latitude and longitude with file Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

I'm trying to open this map with the latitude and longitude of a Json file, but I'm not able to put the marker, it's just opening the map.

I am accessing a json file by PHP and creating a variable array, right after I am sending this array to the javascript with the latitude and longitude points. but it is not opening and displaying the markers.

Anyone know what's going on? below is the code I'm doing.

**file Points.Json**

```
{
"points":[
            {
                "id"        :"01",
                "name"      :"marker01",
                "latitude"  :"-23.538241",
                "longitude" :"-46.647703"
            },
            {
                "id"        :"02",
                "name"      :"marker02",
                "latitude"  :"-23.551258",
                "longitude" :"-46.656243"
            },
            {
                "id"        :"03",
                "name"      :"marker03",
                "latitude"  :"-23.559160",
                "longitude" :"-46.624443"
            }
        ]
  }
```

---

```
<?php 
  $fileJson = file_get_contents('points.json');
  $fileJson = json_decode($fileJson);

  foreach ($fileJson->points as $value) {
    $locations[] = array('id'=>$value->id, 'name'=>$value->name, 
    'latitude'=>$value->latitude, 'longitude'=>$value->longitude);
  }
    $locations = json_encode($locations);
  ?>

  <div id="map"></div>
```

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.538241, -46.647703),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

 var locationdata = '{"locations":<?php echo $locations; ?>}';

  var locations = [];
  var markers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < locationdata.locations.length; i++) {
    var marker_location = locationdata.locations;
    createMarker(marker_location[i],markers,myMap);
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(myMap, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });
}

initMap();

function createMarker(marker_location, markers, myMap) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker_location.latitude, marker_location.longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      'position': latLng,
      map:map,
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    var i_box = '<div>nome :'+ marker_location.nome +'<br>Latitude :' + marker_location.latitude + '<br>Longitude :' + marker_location.longitude + '</div>';

    var myOptions = {
      content: i_box,
      disableAutoPan: false,
      maxWidth: 0,
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-100, -100),
      zIndex: null,
      boxStyle: {
        background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
        opacity: 1,
        width: "200px"
      },
      closeBoxMargin: "0px 0px 0px 0px",
      closeBoxURL: "https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
      infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
      isHidden: false,
      pane: "floatPane",
      enableEventPropagation: false
    };

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
      ib.open(myMap, this);
    });
    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
}
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fafafa;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
 color: #454545;
 line-height: 15px;}


#maps{height:400px;width:100%;background:#ddd;}
#maps img{max-width:inherit}


#map{height:400px;width:100%;background:#ddd;}
#map img{max-width:inherit}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBox3TvUA_j5u4bDmVLXvbtzO7F6y19piA&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How have you tried to 'open' the file? Surely it can be done with an XMLHTTPRequest.

Comment: You are getting issue in parsing that JSON or you are not able to plot the markers on UI ?

Comment: What do you mean by "open the bookmarks in google maps"?  Are you trying to display markers at these locations (perhaps with InfoWindows)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very in depth example on what you're trying to do: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

For future issues you should go through the examples they provide on the Google Maps API, they are very helpful and provide step-by-step instructions